# Is there a way to use the information stored in a database to determine what web page the user is sent to when signed in?

Tags: php, session

Using the information gathered from the a tutorial site I created a website to have users log in and when logging into the account the user selects to create either a Personal account or a Business account. These are stored in the mySQL database as UserType.

The problem I am having is when the user logs in it and it is not reading the UserType at all. It keeps going straight into the else statement.

```
    <?php

// Initialize the session
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT UserType FROM `users` WHERE `username' = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);
// Redirect to Correct Type of Account page
 if (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))== "Personal") {
                echo "Personal";
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'personalInfo.php'; </script>";
            }
 else {
                echo "Other";
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'buisnessInfo.php'; </script>";
            }

?>
```

The results would be that if the user has "Personal" as their UserType in the database then they would go to the personalInfo.php page and if not they would be sent to the other page. Right now they automatically go to buisnessInfo.php

Comment: Typo: Double `= =`

Comment: **Danger**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the all supported versions of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and upgrade to a version of PHP which receives security fixes.

Comment: The result of `mysql_fetch_array` was always an array, so it would never equal a string. Your if statement logic is incorrect.

Comment: Do not use mysql_ functions. They have been removed from PHP. Mysqli is very similar. Change your code and update your answer. Even the site you point to uses mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the code a little bit so we can see what's going on, and replacing mysql with mysqli library as others have recommended produces a desired output:

```
<?php

// Initialize the session
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "Gregory";
echo $_SESSION['username'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

$query = "SELECT UserType FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username) . "' LIMIT 1";

echo "<p>" . $query . "</p>";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query); 
// Redirect to Correct Type of Account page


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";


if ( $row[0] === "Personal" ) {
    echo "Personal";
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'personalInfo.php'; </script>";
            }
 else {
     echo "Other";
     //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'buisnessInfo.php'; </script>";
 }


// or, you can swap the $row[0] with the associative array key $row['UserType']:

if ( $row['UserType'] === "Personal" ) {
    echo "Personal";
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'personalInfo.php'; </script>";
}
else {
    echo "Other";
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'buisnessInfo.php'; </script>";
}

?>
```

Finally, I output the query string so that I can test it in the SQL dialogue of PhpMyAdmin, to see if my sql has any errors.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out my own answer after looking through and reading the comments.

```
<?php

// Initialize the session
session_start();

//echo $_SESSION['username'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

//echo $_SESSION['UserType'];
$UserType = $_SESSION['UserType'];


if ( $UserType == "Personal" ) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'personalInfo.php'; </script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'buisnessInfo.php'; </script>";
}

?>
```